# How to install gh CLI library using conda's environment.yml?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, github-cli

According to the [gh instructions](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), we can install the `gh` cli via conda using: `conda install gh --channel conda-forge`. I wonder if there is way to include it in the `environment.yml` file? So that I can auto install the packages while setting up the conda environment.

```
name: conda_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python>=3.8
  - pip>=20.1.1
```

I don't know where to add `gh` in the `environment.yml` file. Clearly, it is not a pip package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `conda-forge` to the channels and `gh` to the dependencies:

**environment.yaml**

```yaml
name: conda_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python>=3.8
  - pip>=20.1.1
  - gh
```

Note it is recommended when using Conda Forge to give it priority over *defaults* (hence, the order). Otherwise, one risks encountering [channel mixing issues](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Likely not an issue here, since `gh` is a standalone binary, but worth being aware of.